# Is it possible to enable software RAID 1 on Windows XP system partition?

Tags: windows-xp, raid, software-raid, raid-1

I have heard, that it should be somehow possible to use just one partition with Windows XP, and be able to mirror that by enabling RAID 1 in XP. I'd appreciate tips how to do this.

If this is true, is it also possible to enable RAID for an existing Windows installation?

Comment: you want to mirror it ... to what? another drive? another partition on the same drive?

Comment: Nauturally I would like to mirror it to a second drive

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP/2003 and later versions has mechanism called "Dynamic disks". But you can create mirrored drives only in 2003 server and XP Pro.

More information about dynamic disks [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314343)

Comment: XP Pro doesn't support creating mirrored dynamic disks. However, I think that if one had a mirror set up in advance (with, say, 2003 Server), XP could be installed onto it.

Comment: I have a mirrored volume in XP pro. Want a screenshot? It's mirrored with Disk Management

Comment: @Luke: I also have a mirrored volume in XP Pro. However, enabling this functionality in XP Pro requires a hack. In "normal" XP Pro it is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

During the initial XP installation, at the very beginning you get a message where the installer asks you to press the F6 key to install third-party drivers. Keep yours eyes open, it doesn't wait for long. Press the button and you'll be prompted to enter a floppy disk. Your RAID controller should come with one. Just use that and follow instructions.

As for your second question I'm not sure, but you might want to look here:

> [Is it possible to enable RAID 1 without reinstalling Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/91076/is-it-possible-to-enable-raid-1-without-reinstalling-windows)

Comment: I don't mean hardware RAID (aka one implemented with RAID in SATA adapter), but a software-only RAID included in Windows.

Comment: The button is F6, not F2 (I corrected your answer for you).